# What are the next-simplest area-minimizing cones?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-analysis, minimal-surfaces

The simplest area-minimizing, codimension one cones $\mathbf{C} \subset \mathbf{R}^{n+1}$ are the Simons cones. I am trying to understand the behavior of area-minimizing cones a bit better, but these cones are 'special' in a variety of ways that most area-minimizing cones are not.

**Question.** What are the 'next-simplest' cones to consider? The Lawson cones come to mind - is one of them particularly easy to 'see', or particularly instructive in some way? What is your go-to cone when testing some idea?

Comment: Simons cone x R. Not a joke. Considerably different from the Simons cone, eg there is a nonintegrable Jacobi field

Comment: Can you define Simons cones?

Comment: @OtisChodosh Thanks Otis, I'll keep that in mind - I didn't expect this answer! PS. I hope it's OK if I leave the question open for now; I'm curious what comments other people might have.